# Cant not run pikaday.js in WebForm with site master

Tags: asp.net

In the webform with sitemaster, i couldnt use the function of pikaday,but in the new webform i created for testing without sitemaster i could use the function. How do i solve the problems?

With sitemaster:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="pikaday.js"></script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <script>
            var picker = new Pikaday({
                field: document.getElementById('TextBox1'),
                firstDay: 1,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                minDate: new Date('2015-01-01'),
                maxDate: new Date('2050-12-31'),
                yearRange: [2015, 2050],
                numberOfMonths: 1,

            });

        </script> </asp:Content>
```

Without sitemaster:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <link href="css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="moment.js"></script>
        <script src="pikaday.js"></script>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <script>
            var picker = new Pikaday({
                field: document.getElementById('TextBox1'),
                firstDay: 1,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                minDate: new Date('2015-01-01'),
                maxDate: new Date('2050-12-31'),
                yearRange: [2015, 2050],
                numberOfMonths: 1,

            });

        </script>
    </div>
    </form> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly the same problem and after doing research I found out the following: it seems that there's a css property that needs to be changed on the pikaday.css file, specifically on line 35:

```
.pika-single.is-bound{position: absolute !important}
```

Just add the !important next to the "position: absolute" statement.

Also in your javascript you have to reference the textbox like this:

```
var $txtDate = $("[id$=Client_Id_Generated_by_Aspx_page]")
```

This selector will find the reference of the textbox ID that you assigned on the ASPX page on your IDE (for example Visual Studio) at the end, according to the "$=" operator. This applies for .Net Frameworks 3.5 or less since it seems that on .Net Framework 4.0 or more there is a way to assign a ClientID on the server side for you to use it on the frontEnd (.js files for example).

I hope this will help you.

Cheers...